# Testing that something didn't change asynchronously (React, vitest)

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, testing, jestjs, vitest

I've got a custom hook that fetches data, as can be seen in the hook code. In case that "country" is not provided, the useEffect short circuits - meaning loading = true when returned. The comp shows the component using this hook, and as you can see, if loading is indeed true, it returns a loading message. What I can't seem to do is to test that asynchronically, "Loading..." is shown in case no country is provided. That is, that "Loading..." **continues** to be shown even after the hook runs (persists and isn't replaced by anything else).

Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import createUrl from '../helpers/createUrl';
import parseXML from '../helpers/parseXML';

export default function useNewsFetch({ country, topic }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      if (!country) {
        return;
      }
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const url = createUrl(country, topic);
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const xml = await res.text();
        const json = parseXML(xml);
        json.country = country;
        setData(json);
        setError(null);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err);
        setData(null);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, [country, topic]);

  return [data, loading, error];
}
```

Component:

```
import { useParams, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useNewsFetch from '../hooks/useNewsFetch';
import News from './News';

function FetchNews({}) {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const { topicId: topic } = useParams();
  const country = searchParams.get('country');

  const [data, loading, error] = useNewsFetch({ country, topic });

  if (loading) return <h1>Loading...</h1>;

  if (error) return <h1>Error...</h1>;

  return <News newsData={data} />;
}

export default FetchNews;
```

Testing that loading appears first anyways is easy - I use a getBy matcher and expect it to be in the document, and I use queryBy matchers to assert no error or data is present. Testing that the data is shown is also easy, using an await findBy matcher for the data. What I can't seem to do is to test that asynchronically, "Loading..." is shown in case no country is provided. An "await findBy" test for loading is meaningless, because "Loading..." will always be shown first. What I want to test is that after a period of time (for the async useEffect hook to run) it is still "Loading..." that is shown, and not the data. So if I cannot await the data (it will never show - and the test will throw an error) and there's no point in awaiting the loading (will pass the test immediately not testing what I actually want), what can I do?